# Executable Jar not Displaying Output

Tags: java, command-line, jar, command, executable

I have an executable jar that I know is executing, because I put two distinct beeps at the beginning of the code that I hear whenever I double click on it or when I run it through the cli. Even when I run it through the command line however, it does not display output nor prompt for input when I use System.out/System.in respectively. Everything is functional when I run it through eclipse.

How do I get the .jar to output/input to the same command line I executed it in?

Comment: It should do that already, unless something weird happened to STDIN/STDOUT, most likely outside of Java. How exactly do you launch it (on which OS)? Also, could there be buffering in play?

Comment: are you using a logging library? perhaps its logging level is set above the logging statements in your code.

Comment: I am launching it in Windows 7. I go to its directory and then do >myProgram.jar. It immediately gives me a new line, even before the program has finished executing the two beeps I have just realized. Where is the standard out going?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming java is in your PATH, you should lauch your program as follows :

```
java -jar myProgram.jar
```

If you want to run it without opening the command line, you could create a .cmd file in the same directory with this content :

```
@echo off
java -jar myProgram.jar
pause
```

then, double-click on the .cmd file.